# Why can't I compile this DMD snippet?

Tags: dmd

What's wrong with this snippet where `sample` is of type `string`?

```
import core.stdc.stdlib: system;
   
...

compilationResult = system("rdmd -w -wi " ~ sample);
```

It worked with earlier versions but henever I compile it under *DMD64 D Compiler v2.100.0-dirty* it fails and output the following error message.

```
source_code.d(95): Error: function `core.stdc.stdlib.system(scope const(char*) string)` is not callable using argument types `(string)`
```

How should I cast the `system()` function's argument correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to update some *Nick Sabalausky*'s very old DLang code but interesting (written then under DMD 2.053 I guess), get them working under current DMD 2.100 and incidentely found the solution:

1. Add `std.string : toStringz;` to the import clauses
2. Wrap any parameter passed to `system()` with `toStringz` so as to satisfy it's new signature
3. Update the former module owning `system()` with `core.stdc.stdlib` further to **cumulative changes** of the compiler